# How to maximize $u$ here?

Tags: calculus

> Let $u=1-h-w+3hw, 0\leq h,w\leq1$. We want to maximize $u$ given different values of $h$. If $h>\dfrac13$, $w=1$ maximizes $u$.If $h<\dfrac13$, $w=0$ maximizes $u$. And for $h=\dfrac13$, $u$ is independent of values of $w$.

I can see these by putting some numerical values but can't handle it generally. Is there some partial derivative test?

Comment: Do you have the variables correct as you show $-w+3w$?

Comment: SORRY, SIR, and thank you for correction!

Comment: If $w$ is fixed, $u=(3w-1)h+(1-w)$ and hence the result appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, simply apply a partial derivative test. $h$ is fixed so we want to look at: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial w}=-1+3h$$
Now, notice that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial w}<0$ when $h<\frac13$ so $u$ is strictly decreasing with respect to $w$. This means it achieves a maximum at the minimum value of $w$ which is $w=0$. You can apply a similar logic to $h>\frac13$. For $h=\frac13$ notice that all the $h$'s cancel and so $u$ is indeed independent of $h$.

Comment: correction :
$h=\frac{1}{3}$ not $w$.

Comment: @SurajM.S Thank you! It is fixed now.